# Magento 1.7.0.2 Fatal error: Call to a member function getInputType() on a non-object

Tags: php, magento-1.7, magento

I've just upgraded to Magento 1.7.0.2 and am having two problems that I think are related.

(1)  Upon editing or adding a product, I get the following message:

```
    Fatal error: Call to a member function getInputType() on a non-object in /home/.../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product.php on line 995
```

I have the Developer Debug profiler turned on and it gives me this additional information:

```
    {{{Images}}{{Images}}{{Images}}{{Mage_Catalog}}}

    {{{Image type and information need to be specified for each store view.}}{{Image type and information need to be specified for each store view.}}{{Image type and information need to be specified for each store view.}}{{Mage_Catalog}}}
```

In the product.php referenced in the fatal error message, the code around line 995 is as follows:

```
     ** Media API
     */
        /**
         * Retrive attributes for media gallery
         *
         * @return array
         */
         public function getMediaAttributes()
        {
            if (!$this->hasMediaAttributes()) {
                $mediaAttributes = array();
                foreach ($this->getAttributes() as $attribute) {
                    if($attribute->getFrontend()->getInputType() == 'media_image') {
                        $mediaAttributes[$attribute->getAttributeCode()] = $attribute;
                    }
                }
                $this->setMediaAttributes($mediaAttributes);
            }
            return $this->getData('media_attributes');
        }
```

The catalog appears fine; sales appears fine; I've reindexed and emptied caches (multiple times). I don't have any extensions (yet); I have installed a theme but have set it as default in one store and have the same problem. I have a multi-store installation with the addon domain method and all of the stores are exhibiting the same problems.

(2)  The other problem I have is that on the frontend, all product pages result in a 404 error. (Catalog, cms and even searches are ok - it looks to be just the product pages.)

I'm more of an 'enthusiast programmer' and am in a bit over my head. I think I'm close but am stuck. Thank you so much for any help or suggestions you might offer.

Cheers!
Penny

Comment: Hi Penny - a couple of questions for you: Do you use the Magento Compiler in Magento?  If so, and you did not turn it off prior to running updates, this could certainly cause the problem.  There's fairly specific steps that need to be run when updating Magento or installing modules, otherwise this very sort of thing can take place.

Comment: I don't believe I use the Magento Compiler, though I must admit that I'm not sure where it is. I'm generally careful about upgrades but this time (sadly) I was in a time-crunch and short-cutted some things. :( -- update: I just checked the System - config - Advanced and all modules (incl Compiler) are enabled. Is this new since 1.4? (It's been some time since I had done an upgrade.) Do I have any other options other than starting back at 1.4 again?

Comment: If it was compiled, then really that would be your best bet.

Comment: Thank you, Cale! That's what I'm doing. :(